# Magento 2 checkout url edit #payment

Tags: magento2, checkout, url

I have a one question.

Maybe, someone have successfully **(and using good practices)** changed url part to other word.

For example : From **#payment** to  **#quote**  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way.

Each step is registered separately using js.
For example payment step is registered there:

`Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/payment.js` it just enough to change step code in the `stepNavigator.registerStep()` method on the line 54.
from payment->quote. 
Currently I haven't seen any issues there. So it should work.